# Creating a React table that has drag & Drop and Cut-paste ability

Tags: react-table

I want to create a table that can drag and drop selected cells as well as cut - paste cell contentsinside a table. It should also be able to drag and drop selected cell from another list to the main list.  I've look at other solutions  but I have observed that the available solutions either support drag-and-drop or cut paste feature. I have been looking for other solutions out there and even trying to build this functionality myself in React. Would need some  recommendations other solutions that could help achieve this functionality.